# Как правильно создать сумму(сигма) в Си?

Tags: c, математика, ряды, численные-методы

Написал свой код для суммы,но он выводит неправильный ответ.В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){ 
  
    int i,n,sum; 
    double sum2,j; 
        sum = 0; 
        for (i = 1;i <= 5;i++){ 
            sum += (2*i)*(sin(i+1)); 
            sum2 = 1; 
        } 
             
        for (j = 1;j <= 5;j++){ 
                sum2 *= (j + cos(j)); 
                printf("\n Ответ: %f",sum / sum2); 
            } 
             
         
    }
```

Comment: В неверном подсчете...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за ответ,но в каком моменте?

Comment: См. ответ. У вас произведение считается один раз, и не до i, а до n. Вы его, скажем так, попытались вынести из-под знака суммы, а этого делать нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как это посчитать верно:

```
double y(int n)
{
    double p = 1, s = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        p *= i + cos(i);
        s += i * sin(i+1)/p;
    }
    return 2*s;
}
```

У вас произведение считается как произведение от 1 до n, а на самом деле?